# HTTPClient call is not returning correct JSON data in Appcelerator Titanium app

Tags: javascript, java, json, titanium, appcelerator

Everytime i try to get my info from a JSON i get an error.

```
function buscar(e){
    var url = 'https://www.dotscancun.com/createjson.php?id=100001';
    var xhr = Ti.Network.HTTPClient({
    onerror: function(e){
        Ti.API.info(this.responseText);
        Ti.API.info(this.status);
        Ti.API.info(e.error);
        },
        timeout: 5000
    });   
    xhr.open('GET',url);
    xhr.send();
    xhr.onload = function(){ 
        var json = JSON.parse(this.responseText); 
        alert(json);
    };
};
```

This is the Code.

The error is:

```
[LiveView] Client connected
[ERROR] :  TiHTTPClient: (TiHttpClient-8) [1340,1340] HTTP Error (java.io.IOException): 404 : Not Found
[ERROR] :  TiHTTPClient: java.io.IOException: 404 : Not Found
[ERROR] :  TiHTTPClient:    at ti.modules.titanium.network.TiHTTPClient$ClientRunnable.run(TiHTTPClient.java:1217)
[ERROR] :  TiHTTPClient:    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
```

Error 404 it means that the website didnt exist, but if you copy the url it works, what is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error message you have posted in your question is not related to your JSON query. Rather it's related to your Android device log output. So you can simply ignore that call.

You are coding it wrong because:

- You are not creating a proper HTTPClient object. You are using **Ti.Network.HTTPClient** instead of **Ti.Network.createHTTPClient**
- **onload** method should be defined before **open()** call.

Here's the correct code for your question:

```
function buscar(e){
    var url = 'https://www.dotscancun.com/createjson.php?id=100001';

    var xhr = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient({
        onerror: function(e){
            Ti.API.info(this.responseText);
            Ti.API.info(this.status);
            Ti.API.info(e.error);
        },

        timeout: 5000,

        onload : function(){
            alert(this.responseText);

            // parse it for further use
            var tempJSON = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
        }
    });

    xhr.open('GET',url);
    xhr.send();
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that the app will crash when the request returns no JSON. Create a helper function which parses JSON by using a try and catch, this is much more fail safe.

Comment: @Gerben, yeah, but didn't mention it in code just because to give that user a clear & simple idea of how to use client call. I believe he can use try-catch on his own. That's why I didn't remove the timeout as well because it's not always sure that picture is downloaded within 5 seconds, so it will help him to understand things further.